# Is it safe to Uploading to azure blob through xhr request in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Iam implenting a project with angular2 as front end and Laravel as backend.
In this project i am uploading the files to Azure blob through xhr request from front end.
when ever the Xhr request fires the azure blob storage url is showing in network tab in console , and this url contains the signature of the azure blob.

is it ok to implement this functionality through XHR in Javascript. any suggstions will helpa me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it ok to implement this functionality through XHR in Javascript.
>   any suggstions will help me a lot.

I think this is fine as long as you keep the SAS token valid only for the duration it is required to upload the file (It can be tricky thing to guess the actual time it would need to upload a file).

There are a few other things you could do to make it more secure:

- Only include `Write` or `Create` permission in the SAS token. Don't include other permissions like `Read` or `Delete` if you don't need to. This way, user will only upload the file using this SAS token and do nothing else.
- As mentioned above, keep the SAS token validity duration short.
- If possible, get the SAS token only for the file the user is uploading. Don't get a SAS token for the entire blob container. This way, user will only be upload a specific file.
- Include IP ACLing in your SAS token so that user can't share the SAS URL with other users. IP ACLing will enforce SAS URL be used only from the IP address included in the SAS token.

Comment: Thank You @Gaurav Mantri. Thanks for your response. i have inspired from  your article on azure blob storage in link below from you

gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/

I am trying to generate signature at angular 2 type script end with short duration range.